# Induction to find string length equivalence

Tags: algorithms, induction

Rewrite system of RRR ≡ NULL, FF ≡ NULL, RRF ≡ FR.
Show that each string in {F,R}* is equiv. to one of the six strings:
NULL, R, RR, F, FR, FRR.
A hint is to use induction and ask if every string of length <=2 equiv. to one of the six strings. If a string w has length n ≥ 2, then
either w = Rx with length of x = n − 1,
or w = F x with length of x = n − 1.)

Am I understanding it correctly by saying the R string from the six is not equiv. because it doesn't match the rewrite system given?

Comment: Am I missing something?  What is RF equivalent to?

Comment: @BrianTung RF is not given

Comment: Right, but the direction is to show that each string in $\{F, R\}^*$ is equivalent to one of those strings.  RF is in that language, and I don't see how it is equivalent to any of those strings.

Comment: OK. so you are saying the question is confusing?

Answer (score 3):

(Getting another old question off the unanswered list.)

It appears that this is intended to be a symmetric rewrite system (Thue system), and I will assume that this is the case. Let $\Sigma=\{F,R\}$, let $\mathscr{L}_0=\{\lambda,R,RR,F,FR,FRR\}$, where $\lambda$ is the null string, and let

$$\mathscr{L}=\left\{w\in\Sigma^*:\exists u\in\mathscr{L}_0(w\equiv u)\right\}\,;$$

we wish to show that $\mathscr{L}=\Sigma^*$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\Sigma_n=\left\{w\in\Sigma^*:|w|\le n\right\}$; clearly it suffices to show that $\Sigma_n\subseteq\mathscr{L}$ for all $n\ge 2$

Every member of $\Sigma_2$ except $FF$ and $RF$ is in $\mathscr{L}_0$ and hence in $\mathscr{L}$, and $FF\equiv\lambda\in\mathscr{L}_0$, so $FF\in\mathscr{L}$. And

$$RF=\lambda RF\equiv RRRRF\equiv RRFR\equiv FRR\in\Sigma_0\,,$$

where the last two equivalences follow from the equivalence $RRF\equiv FR$. Thus, $\Sigma_2\subseteq\mathscr{L}$.

Now suppose that $\Sigma_n\subseteq\mathscr{L}$ for some $n\ge 2$, and let $w\in\Sigma_{n+1}\setminus\Sigma_n$; then there is an $x\in\Sigma_n$ such that $w\in\{Fx,Rx\}$. By hypothesis $x\in\mathscr{L}$, so there is a $u\in\mathscr{L}_0$ such that $w\equiv Fu$ or $w\equiv Ru$. If $u\in\Sigma_1$, then $Fu,Ru\in\Sigma_2\subseteq\mathscr{L}$, so $w\in\mathscr{L}$. The remaining possibilities are

- $w\equiv FRR\in\mathscr{L}_0$,
- $w\equiv FFR\equiv\lambda R=R\in\mathscr{L}_0$,
- $w\equiv FFRR\equiv\lambda RR=RR\in\mathscr{L}_0$,
- $w\equiv RRR\equiv\lambda\in\mathscr{L}_0$,
- $w\equiv RFR\equiv RRRF\equiv\lambda F=F\in\mathscr{L}_0$, and
- $w\equiv RFRR\equiv FR\in\mathscr{L}_0$ (since $RFR\equiv F$),

and in each case $w\in\mathscr{L}$. Thus, $\Sigma_{n+1}\subseteq\mathscr{L}$, and the result follows by induction.